# How to set up IntelliJ external Scala compiler for Maven projects

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13 community version. I have a Maven project with multiple modules.
Currently, I'm using IntelliJ internal compiler. I find that every time I run maven clean XXX, I have to manually trigger Scala rebuild in IntelliJ before I run any Cucumber acceptance tests. Otherwise IntelliJ will complaints "no class file". It is annoying. It takes 2 to 3 minutes for the clean re-build.

Finally, I decide to try the external compiler. I have no idea how to do it. I does not seems as easy as enable external compiler.

Can any one please teach me how to properly set up external compiler for a multi-module maven Scala project?

Answer (score 0):

Maven clean command deletes your jar and target folder.
therefor you need to compile the maven project with the maven command "compile" / "install" after clean .
if you want to use your command line to clean and compile you can run `$ mvn clean compile` . but actually since "clean" is the 1st step at maven's build life cycle **you only need to run the compile command** . it will run "clean" (or `$ mvn compile`) as the 1st step of the build  .

check out [maven build life cycle here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thanks fot the reply. I need to run clean step though. I was a bit confused about which compiled source dir IntelliJ uses when it is a maven project. IntelliJ allows you to specify a separate dir when uses external compiler mode. Yet it seems if it is a maven project, the specified dir is ignore. The key question here is, can IntelliJ use a external compiler with a separate dir for compiled sources.